# is $node always available in page.tpl.php

Tags: 7, theming

I'm periodically getting an error about $node being undefined in one of my template files.I have a simple if condition that checks the node type being displayed. I assumed $node is always available, or am I wrong?

Comment: Might want to flag this as answered so others can use this question :)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

$node isn't necessarily defined, from the [page.tpl.php Drupal 7 API](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules--system--page.tpl.php/7):

> $node: The node object, if there is an
>   automatically-loaded node associated
>   with the page, and the node ID is the
>   second argument in the page's path
>   (e.g. node/12345 and
>   node/12345/revisions, but not
>   comment/reply/12345).

Answer (score 8):

By default, only on node pages is the $node variable defined.    For the front page (a feed),  view pages, comment, etc, they are not.

If you want a $node variable defined on a page that it is not a node, then you will have to edit/create the MYTHEME_preprocess_page(&$variables) function in your theme template.php file.

To avoid your error, in your template file wrap the $node variable in an

```
if (isset($node)) {
  // do something with $node
}
```

Or remove it completely

Comment: $node can be a defined variable on page.tpl.php

Comment: by default, yes,  if its a NODE.  If it is not, then it is not defined.  Get your facts straight, and don't be downvoting a valid answer.

Comment: Statement "Only on node pages is the $node variable define." isn't valid.