# How to output content type title on page.tpl.php?

Tags: 7, theming

So I am using this code to output nodes title:

```
<?php print render($title_prefix); ?>
<?php if ($title): ?><h2 class="title" id="page-title"><?php print $title; ?></h2><?php endif; ?>
<?php print render($title_suffix); ?>
```

What code do I need to output the content type's name (i.e. content type is Article, so output 'Article' inside each Article content type node page next to node title, above or below it)?

Comment: You don't have a $node in page.tpl.php

Comment: @AyeshK yes you do: http://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/6626/is-node-always-available-in-page-tpl-php

Answer (score 11, accepted):

In D7 there is [node_type_get_name](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!node!node.module/function/node_type_get_name/7)

```
node_type_get_name($node)
```

**Parameters**

> $node: A node object or string that indicates the node type to return

**Return value**

> The node type name or FALSE if the node type is not found.

Comment: This shoud be used in addition to the check isset($node) to avoid notices from PHP

Answer (score 2):

You can access the $node object in page.tpl.php typically, as [long as a $node object exists](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/6626/is-node-always-available-in-page-tpl-php) (i.e. you are on a node page). So you can use:

```
if (isset($node)) {
  // do something with $node
}
```

If you want to inspect $node (or anything else for that matter), you can use [Devel module](http://drupal.org/project/devel). When installed and enabled, it provides a function, [`dpm()`](http://api.drupal.org/api/devel/devel.module/function/dpm/7), that will let you inspect arrays, objects, etc. as long as you are logged in as a user with permissions to view it. so `dpm($node)` will allow you to inspect the $node object.

The value closest to what you want is probably `$node->type`, but as MPD pointed out, that will give you a machine name, with spaces converted to underscores.

If you want to do it without writing any code, your best option is probably to use [Views](http://drupal.org/project/views) or [Panels](http://drupal.org/project/panels) to pull that value and display it.

If you don't want to use those, here's how you would do it with a block:

1. Create a block for the content type you want to display.
2. Make the content "My Content Type Name" or whatever.
3. Set the block to display in whatever region you want.
4. Set the block to only display on content of "My Content Type Name".
5. Save the block.

Comment: Thanks for helping, but like I mentioned, I am a beginner and I have no experience on PHP at all. All I know is how to paste in code to template.php and etc. I am a designer - not a programmer, sadly. So I am pretty much not sure what to write in.

Comment: http://php.net/print

Comment: $node->type is just the machine name, not the pretty name

Answer (score 0):

If article is your content type machine name ,

```
<?php 
if($node_details->type == 'article'){
   print 'Article or $node_details->type';
 } 
?>
```

it will print your content type name in all of is node.Print this in you page.tpl before print $content so that you can print it before the node title.

Comment: if you don't know the machine name of your content type, simply print the $node_details = node_load(arg(1)); and get the value of $node_details->type, this is the machine name of your content type .

Comment: `$node->type` will give you the machine name faster. If the thing being viewed is a node, you will have access to the `$node` object.